# How To Set Different Icons for an AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-emulator

for example if we get an error then it show appropriate icon for this behavior like wrong and right icons.

```
if(condition true)
{
  //here i need set right icon
}
if(condition false)
 {
 //here i need set wrong icon
AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
ad.seticon();//how to set for different behavior
```

Comment: Both the answers give almost the same advice, you should accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an `int` to hold the drawable id for false/wrong (as a default value), then if it's true/right, change what `resId` points to. If you don't want an icon as default, make `resId` equal to 0. Then set the icon after making the AlertDialog.

```
int resId = R.drawable.false;

if(condition == true)
{
  resId = R.drawable.true;
}

 //here i need set wrong icon
AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
ad.setIcon(resId);//how to set for different behavior
```

Of course, make sure that you have `true` and `false` pictures in your `res/drawable` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Set `resource id` of `correct/wrong` image and just call the method and show the dialog with appropriate icons.

```
int res_id=0;

  if(condition true)
  {
       res_id = R.drawable.correct;
       myDialog(res_id);
  }

 if(condition false)
  {

        res_id = R.drawable.wrong;
        myDialog(res_id);
   }

  void myDialog(int resId){

        AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
        ad.setIcon(resId);

   }
```